nestjs project having problem with rabbitmq emit function not sending message
I'm having problem sending message from my auth service to my admin service. when I use emit function nothing happens(prints) on terminal.
this is my app.module
  TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports : [ConfigModule],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService): any => ({
      type: "mysql", // type of sql
      host: "localhost",
      port: "3306",
      username: "root",
      password: ...,
      database: ....,
      entities: [User, Product, Order, Item], // class that we want to make a table from them
      autoLoadEntities : true, // this will automatically add entities to array when we use that entity in forFeature method (recomended)
      //Note that entities that aren't registered through the forFeature() method, but are only referenced from the entity (via a relationship), won't be included by way of the autoLoadEntities setting.
      synchronize: true, // if we modify any entities it update synchronozily tables in db
    }),
    inject: [ConfigService],
  }),
  AuthModule,
  // ProductModule,
  AdminModule
],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, appRepository],
  
})
export class AppModule {}

app.main
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AuthModule);
  const rmqSer = app.get(rabitmqService, {strict : false});
  app.connectMicroservice(rmqSer.getOptions("AUTH"));
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  // await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

auth.module
@Module({
  imports: [  rabitmqModule.register({
    name : "ADMIN_NOTIF"
  }),
  JwtModule.register({}),
  TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]) // for using them in app.module its important to register them with forfeature
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, authRepository],
})
export class AuthModule {}


auth.service
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private config : ConfigService, private userRep : authRepository, private readonly jwt : JwtService, @Inject("ADMIN_NOTIF") private adminClient : ClientProxy ){}
  async signUp(dto : signUpDto , res : Response){
        try {
            const password = dto.password;
            const size: number = Number(this.config.get("SALT_PASSWORD"));
            const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password , size);
            const user = await this.userRep.create(dto , hash);
            if (user.role == Roles.Admin){
              this.adminClient.emit("new_admin_created" , {username :  user.username})
            }
            const token = await this.jwtSign(user.username);
            res.cookie("Authentication", token , {
              httpOnly : true,
            })
            return token;
        }catch(error){
            throw error;
        }
        
  }

  async signIn(userData : signInDto , res : Response){
    const user = await this.userRep.find(userData.username);
    if (!user){
      throw new ForbiddenException("credential incorrect");
    }

    const result = bcrypt.compare(userData.password , user.password);
    if (!result){
      throw new ForbiddenException("Password incorrect");
    }
    const token = this.jwtSign(user.username);
    res.cookie("Authentication", token , {
      httpOnly : true,
    })
  }

  async jwtSign(userId : string): Promise<string>{
    const payload = {id : userId }//id sub
    return await this.jwt.signAsync(payload ,{
        expiresIn : '60m',
        secret : this.config.get("JWT_SECRET")
    });
}
}


auth.main
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AuthModule);
  const rmqSer = app.get(rabitmqService, {strict : false});
  app.connectMicroservice(rmqSer.getOptions("AUTH"));
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  // await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

admin.module
@Module({
  imports: [rabitmqModule.register({
    name : "AUTH"
  }),],
  controllers: [AdminController],
  providers: [AdminService],
})
export class AdminModule {}

admin.controller
@Controller()
export class AdminController {
  constructor(private readonly adminService: AdminService) {}

  @EventPattern("new_admin_created")
  newadminNotif(@Payload() payload : any , @Ctx() context : RmqContext){
    console.log(payload);
  }
}

admin.main
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AdminModule);
  const rmqSer = app.get(rabitmqService, {strict : false});
  app.connectMicroservice(rmqSer.getOptions("ADMIN_NOTIF"));
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
}
bootstrap();

rabbitmq.module
@Module({
    providers : [rabitmqService],
    exports  : [rabitmqService]
})
export class rabitmqModule {
    static register({name}): DynamicModule { // return value is json object type
        return {
            module : rabitmqModule , 
            imports : [ClientsModule.registerAsync([{
                name,
                useFactory : (configSer : ConfigService) => ({
                    transport : Transport.RMQ,
                    options : {
                        urls : ["amqp://rabbitmq:5672"],
                        queue : configSer.get(`RABITMQ_${name}_QUEUE`)
                    }
                }),
                inject : [ConfigService]
            }])],
            exports : [ClientsModule]          
        }
    }
}


rabbbitmq.service
@Injectable()
export class rabitmqService {
    constructor(private readonly configSer : ConfigService){}

    getOptions(queue : string ,noAck = false ):RmqOptions { // single place to confogure rabitmq option for all microservices
        return {
            transport : Transport.RMQ,
            options : {
                urls : this.configSer.get("RABITMQ_URL"), // specify url that rabitmq is listening on or other brokers
                persistent : true, // if for some reason broker stoped,we can restore the list of messages
                queue : this.configSer.get(`RABITMQ_${queue}_QUEUE`),
                noAck, //set rmq aknoledgmant manually
            }
        }
    }

    ack(context : RmqContext){
        const message = context.getMessage();
        const channel = context.getChannelRef();
        channel.ack(message) // deqeueu message from queue
    }
}

I think the problem relates to my main files and logic of them bc at the moment I don't know actually how to make some microservices.
my goal is to notify admins when we signup new admin and print something on terminal. thanks
